# Inserir dentro de array, cujo valor da propriedade pai seja igual ao valor da propriedade do objeto filho

Tags: javascript, array

Tenho um objeto (Perguntas) e quero que outro objeto (Respostas) seja adicionado a ele de acordo com um id em comum.

```
var Perguntas = [
    { idPergunta: 13, textoPergunta: "Qual seu nome" , Respostas : [] },
    { idPergunta: 26, textoPergunta: "Qual sua idade" , Respostas : [] }        
]

var Respostas = [
    { idPergunta: 13, idResposta: 1, textoResposta: "Joao", ordemResposta: 0 },
    { idPergunta: 13, idResposta: 2, textoResposta: "Jose", ordemResposta: 1 } 
    { idPergunta: 26, idResposta: 3, textoResposta: "15", ordemResposta: 0 },
    { idPergunta: 26, idResposta: 4, textoResposta: "30", ordemResposta: 1} 
]

for(var i = 0; i < Respostas.length; i++){
    Pergunta[?].Respostas = Respostas[i];
}
// Quero evoluir esse código pra chegar a resposta.
```

Quebrei a cabeça, mas ainda não consegui pensar em um algoritmo pra solucionar isso, talvez seja simples e um empurrão vai me ajudar.

Esse código eu fiz de cabeça sem testar, se notarem algum erro de sintaxe me avisem que corrijo. Não sei por exemplo se posso declarar Respostas: [] dentro de Perguntas ou se é só deixar vazio, nulo ou não colocar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Podes fazer assim:

```
Perguntas.forEach(function (pergunta) {
    var id = pergunta.idPergunta;
    pergunta.Respostas = Respostas.filter(function (resposta) {
        return resposta.idPergunta == id; // aqui o filter retira as que derem false
    });
});
```

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/j0fLLLm7/1

```js
var Perguntas = [
    { idPergunta: 13, textoPergunta: "Qual seu nome" , Respostas : [] },
    { idPergunta: 26, textoPergunta: "Qual sua idade" , Respostas : [] }        
]

var Respostas = [
    { idPergunta: 13, idResposta: 1, textoResposta: "Joao", ordemResposta: 0 },
    { idPergunta: 13, idResposta: 2, textoResposta: "Jose", ordemResposta: 1 },
    { idPergunta: 26, idResposta: 3, textoResposta: "15", ordemResposta: 0 },
    { idPergunta: 26, idResposta: 4, textoResposta: "30", ordemResposta: 1} 
]

Perguntas.forEach(function (pergunta) {
    var id = pergunta.idPergunta;
    pergunta.Respostas = Respostas.filter(function (resposta) {
        return resposta.idPergunta == id;
    });
});

alert(JSON.stringify(Perguntas[0], null, 2));
```

A ideia é iterar todas as perguntas e na propriedade `pergunta.Respostas` ir buscar as respostas. Aqui o `.filter()` é muito prático pois verifica todas as respostas e deixa uma array só com  aquelas que tiverem a `id` igual à da pergunta (`resposta.idPergunta == id;`).

Comment: Perfeito, exatamente o que eu queria e com pouco código.

Comment: @JoaoPaulo ótimo!